# Display list of all songs in android music folder in a list

Tags: android

I wanted to create a list of all songs which are present in android phone so that user can select one song from the list. How to do this???

Answer (score 3):

Query the `MediaStore` for all music files. Use the resulting `Cursor` in a `ListView` using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.